# Why does command line devenv and Visual Studio GUI not build the solution the same?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, devenv

I have a solution called MainWindow.vs2015.sln for my Application. This has nearly 100 Projects and it builds perfectly in Visual Studio 2015. When I build the solution from the command line using devenv, it also works perfectly and there are no errors.

However, when I build from the command line, and then open Visual Studio 2015 and build it again, expecting an almost instantaneous build as I had already built from the command line, it builds the whole thing all over again and I am sat there for up to nearly 30 mins waiting for something to build all over again.

Is there some kind of difference between the devenv command and Visual Studio builds?

P.S I have also MSBuild as well as devenv and have had the same problem.

```
devenv MainWindow.vs2015.sln /Build "Debug ALL"
```

Comment: I guess this issue may have something to do with the Configuration+Platform you use when building in command-line and VS, do you build it in same settings?

Comment: It also depends on tools and customisations both in the project but also in VS (e.g. ReSharper) - VS also performs design-time builds to feed to IntelliSense when loading a project. If you use a current version of Visual Studio (2019) solution load should be much faster due to changes in the architecture.

Comment: Hi Faz, any update for this issue? Please check if my answer helps to resolve this issue, if it still blocks you, please feel free to let me know and share more details here :)

Answer (score 0):

What's your project type? VB.net, C# or C++?

**For `.net` projects**:

If we create a new VS2015 C# project in command-line, build it in `Debug+x64` combination. After that when open the project in IDE and build it, it will display Up-To-Date, and won't compile and build again since nothing changes.

So if you meet the `build twice` issue in C# projects, set the Build Output verbosity to `Detailed` or higher in VS to see detailed info about the build process.

After that, when you again meet this issue, trying reading the very first of the log to see the reason why VS builds it again! Check if you have some files missing or set as Copy Always like [this](https://oz-code.com/blog/visual-studio-keeps-rebuilding-projects-no-good-reason/).

**For `C++` projects:**

If you're in a solution with many C++ projects in it. I'm afraid the answer could be negative. I test it in VS2015 C++ projects and I can reproduce same issue. I found if we create a C++ project, build it in command-line and then VS. VS will consider it not to be up-to-date and try to build it again...

Something interesting is if we build it not by command-line, instead we build it twice in VS, VS can recognize it's update-to-date and won't waste time to build it the second time.

So I suggest you could avoid building it in command-line before building in VS. Cause there's no advantage that we build the project using two ways while we don't do actual modify to the source files. Also, since there's something that can be improved about the Up-To-Date check in VS for C++ projects, you can post a `feature request` in DC and you can get help from the Product Team there.

In addition: Please make sure the Configuration+Platform you use to build solution in command-line are the same when you build in VS IDE.

Hope it makes some help :)